# Spring Integration jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter - Set max-rows-per-poll dynamic to throttle

Tags: spring-integration

I have a JDBC:inbound-channel-adapter : To set the 'max-rows-per-poll' dynamic to throttle the messages getting passed on the channel.

I have a QueueChannel which has a capacity of 200. The inbound-channel-adapter would be sending the message to this QueueChannel. I would like to set the 'max-rows-per-poll' value depending on the RemainingCapacity of the QueueChannel.

For this I tried to Inject the QueueChannel in a Bean but I get the error when deploying the war file.

Error: Cannot Inject the QueueChannel due to StateConversionError.

Is there any other way I could achieve this.

Update : I am using Spring-Integration-2.2.0.RC2

This is the config for jdbc-inbound-adapter:

```
<si-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter id ="jdbcInboundAdapter" channel="queueChannel" data-source="myDataSource" auto-startup="true" query="${select.query}"
update="${update.query}" max-rows-per-poll="100"  row-mapper="rowMapper" update-per-row="true">
 <si:poller fixed-rate="5000">
    <si:transactional/>
     <si:advice-chain>
           <bean class="foo.bar.InboundAdapterPollingConfigurationImpl"/>
     </si:advice-chain>
  </si:poller>
</si-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Bean:

```
    @Service
public class InboundAdapterPollingConfigurationImpl implements InboundAdapterPollingConfiguration{

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InboundAdapterPollingConfigurationImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    QueueChannel queueChannel;
    @Autowired
    SourcePollingChannelAdapter jdbcInboundAdapter;

    public void setJdbcInboundAdapterMaxRowsPerPoll(){
        String size = String.valueOf(queueChannel.getRemainingCapacity());
        DirectFieldAccessor directFieldAccessor = new DirectFieldAccessor(jdbcInboundAdapter);      
        directFieldAccessor.setPropertyValue("setMaxRowsPerPoll", size);        
        String maxRowsPerPollSize = (String)directFieldAccessor.getPropertyValue("setMaxRowsPerPoll");
        System.out.println(maxRowsPerPollSize);
    }
}
```

The question is how to call the InboundAdapterPollingConfigurationImpl.setJdbcInboundAdapterMaxRowsPerPoll() method from the advice chain. Sorry for the naive question but t is my first time using the advice-chain. Also I am searching for an example but was not lucky yet.

**Update2:**
Got the below error when this is executed:

```
JdbcPollingChannelAdapter source = (JdbcPollingChannelAdapter)dfa.getPropertyValue("source");
```

Error:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy547 cannot be cast to org.springframework.integration.jdbc.JdbcPollingChannelAdapter –
```

I have the JDK1.6_26. I read in one of the posts that this is happening in the early versions of JDK1.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, let's try to investigate!

1. `max-rows-per-poll` is a volatile property of `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter` with appropriate setter.
2. As far as `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter` does the stuff within its `receive()` method just on the initiative of `TaskScheduler.schedule()` looks like changing that property at runtime is safe. It is a first point for our task
3. `QueueChannel` has property `getQueueSize()`. As far as a `capacity` is your configuration option, so you can simply calculate a value for `max-rows-per-poll`
4. And now how to get it worked? Actually you are interested in the value for `max-rows-per-poll` just on each poll. So, we should somehow to wedge into poller or polling task. Well, `<poller>` has `advice-chain` sub-element and we can write some `Advice`, which should change `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter#setMaxRowsPerPoll` before invoking `receive()` and the value should be based on `QueueChannel#getQueueSize()`
5. Inject your `QueueChannel` to the bean of your `Advice`
6. And now some bad point: how to inject `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter` bean? We provide a hook to register `MessageSources` as beans just only since Spring Integration 3.0. From here it's just enough to write this code:

   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("jdbcAdapter.source")
   private JdbcPollingChannelAdapter messageSource;

We are going to release 3.0.GA this week. So, let me do not consider the reflection 'forest' prior to Sring Integration 3.0. However you can do it using `DirectFieldAccessor` on injected `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` bean.

UPDATE

Your `Advice` may look like this:

```
public class MyAdvice implements MethodInterceptor {
       @Autowired
       QueueChannel queueChannel;

       @Autowired
       SourcePollingChannelAdapter jdbcInboundAdapter; 

      Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
            DirectFieldAccessor dfa = new DirectFieldAccessor(jdbcInboundAdapter);
            JdbcPollingChannelAdapter source = (JdbcPollingChannelAdapter) dfa.getPropertyValue("source");
            source.setMaxRowsPerPoll(queueChannel.getRemainingCapacity());
            return invocation.proceed();
      }
}
```

The theory is here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop

Comment: I am working on it to implement. One quick question: How would you call a specific method from the advice-chain of a referenced bean.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you show a case, or express it in other words. Thanks

Comment: I added an implementation for you. Cheers!

Comment: got this error when this is executed: JdbcPollingChannelAdapter source = (JdbcPollingChannelAdapter) dfa.getPropertyValue("source"); : java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy547 cannot be cast to org.springframework.integration.jdbc.JdbcPollingChannelAdapter

Comment: First of all you should configure `<transactional>` as `<tx:advice>` within `<advice-chain>`. It's not clear why it is ` $Proxy547`. I tested it locally and everyrthin OK. Do you have some specific global AOP configuration? E.g. JMX exposing? Try to find who wraps your `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter` to `Proxy`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43056/discussion-between-john-and-artem-bilan)