# Spring Integration: Error Injecting a QueueChannel in a Bean to calculate RemainingCapacity

Tags: spring-integration

I want to inject a QueueChannel in a bean so that I could monitor the RemainingCapacity of it. It would be great if any one can guide me to fix this.

Below is my Config:

```
<si:channel id="queueChannel">
    <si:queue capacity="200"/>
</si:channel>
<bean id="inboundAdapterPollingConfiguration" class="com.foo.impl.InboundAdapterPollingConfigurationImpl">
        <property name="channel" ref="queueChannel"/>
        <property name="jdbcInboundAdapter" ref="jdbcInboundAdapter"/>      
    </bean>
```

Bean Code:

```
public class InboundAdapterPollingConfigurationImpl implements MethodInterceptor{

QueueChannel channel;

public QueueChannel getChannel() {
    return channel;
}
public void setChannel(QueueChannel channel) {
    this.channel = channel;
}
}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 
[$Proxy336 implementing org.springframework.integration.core.PollableChannel,  
org.springframework.integration.MessageChannel] to required type  
[org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel] 
for property 'channel': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Comment: John, I though we had this covered in the chat from your other question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20501149/spring-integration-jdbcinbound-channel-adapter-set-max-rows-per-poll-dynamic Do you still need help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enable JMX, channels, endpoints etc get wrapped in a proxy; this means you can only inject them using an interface (such as `MessageChannel`). We are looking at options to make this a little easier in the future but, for now, you have to unwrap the proxy to get access to the underlying `QueueChannel` object. [Here is a Gist showing how to do it](https://gist.github.com/garyrussell/7953672).

Answer (score 0):

John, in the our chat you said:

> I am using the JMX Export to get the info about the TaskExecutors in my application and to modify it dynamically

So, there is no need to fight with proxy for your case, because `<int-jmx:mbean-export>` has attribute `managed-components` () and you can just list bean nemas of your executors.
Your `queueChannel` won't be a proxy.

Comment: Thanks Artem but I want to get the QueueChannel instance so that i can get the remaining capacity. I will look in to it tomorrow. Anyhow I got it working by using Garry's Method.